# Television is blinking while connecting to Raspberry Pi

Tags: hdmi

I have changed config in the following way:

```
overscan_left=16
overscan_right=16
overscan_top=16
overscan_bottom=16

framebuffer_width=800
framebuffer_height=600

config_hdmi_boost=6
```

And I am in text mode (no GUI).

With this I have TV blinking with period of several seconds.

Also the TV reports 640x480 on it's `OSD`, despite the fact I see by eyes, that resolution is larger, then when I leave `framebuffer` lines commented. When these lines commented, the `TV` is still blinking.

What else can be done?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen improvement with a different (better quality) HDMI cable, and avoiding HDMI splitters / converters / adapters along the way. Trying a different resolution may also help.

In general however, there are screens which work poorly with the Pi, despite good cables and `config_hdmi_boost`. If this is the case, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: OP does not mention model Pi so just wanted to add that config_hdmi_boost doesn't work on the Pi4 raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md